# How does API work with application server?

Tags: api, http, server

I've read that application server can be accessed via API. But I don't get the mechanism of that process. Does it work like that?

[image]

So, as for me, firstly, client sends an HTTP request to a hardware server. Here we start to looking for some data. Then, we connect with application server via API. And then something that was found in hardware server changes with application server. And after all, client receives this changed file. Am I right?

And it looks like API always works only with application server. Is it true?

Comment: You'll need to specify which application servers you are talking about. If they are systems you are creating/writing, then anything is possible, you can open arbitrary sockets to create connections between any two machines and build APIs that talk over the sockets. You'll also need to specify what a "hardware server" is, that is not an industry standard term, do you mean a database?

Comment: @Brennen Sprimont yeah, I mean database. And yeah, I'm talking about programs that developer can write

Comment: Then you are free to do whatever you'd like. Open some sockets and go to town. Best practice wise, I'd recommend you don't have your "clients" talk directly to your database though. Clients should connect to your application server, which can host traditional html endpoints or "api" endpoints. Some companies host their API endpoints on the same application servers as their html endpoints, some put them on different servers, some build their html app servers by going through the api server to talk to the database. There is no real "right" answer here, every route has pros and cons.